# React Native: Modal overlaps a root component

Tags: css, react-native, modal-dialog

I have such structure of screen:

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
...
<View>
  <MessageBar />
  <Modal>
    <modal content is here>
  </Modal>
</View>
```

`MessageBar` is a rectangle with styles: `{position: absolute, zIndex: 1000}`

As a result, `MessageBar` anyway is overlaped by Modal backdrop. I tried all possible combination with `position` and `zIndex` for both - `Modal` and `MessageBar`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: share the whole `CSS` you tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Modal, then it will always overlap the components on the screen regardless of whatever zIndex you give to the componets.